# Java Jframe ICONIFIED closing failure

Tags: java, swing, jframe, minimize

Thanks to a previous question answered I am now able to start my application as a tray icon ([Java frame iconified issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53440690/java-frame-iconified-issue)), however I am now running into a few different issues and I am having trouble figuring out how to fix them. When the main program runs, the console window indeed no longer launches full screen as intended, however instead of just forming a system tray icon in the bottom right corner, the window also forms a traditional minimized window on the task bar. I have noticed that previously before I made this change, when the "Hide Window" button is pressed, the main taskbar window disappears leaving only the smaller system tray icon in the right corner. It seems the changes recommended in the previous question keeps the window running, but just seems to hide it from view. How can I change this behavior? I only expected to see the small system tray icon in the bottom right corner. Also, upon exiting the main application, the tray icons don't close down. They stay open, sometimes piling up if the main application is launched multiple times. If only I could figure out where the "Hide Window" action was coming from, I feel like I could figure this out, but alas, I cant see to find the actions of that button referenced anywhere in the code. Please help!

```
package com.skcraft.launcher.dialog;

import com.skcraft.launcher.Launcher;
import com.skcraft.launcher.swing.LinedBoxPanel;
import com.skcraft.launcher.swing.MessageLog;
import com.skcraft.launcher.swing.SwingHelper;
import com.skcraft.launcher.util.PastebinPoster;
import com.skcraft.launcher.util.SharedLocale;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NonNull;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import static com.skcraft.launcher.util.SharedLocale.tr;

/**
 * A frame capable of showing messages.
 */
public class ConsoleFrame extends JFrame {

private static ConsoleFrame globalFrame;

@Getter private final Image trayRunningIcon;
@Getter private final Image trayClosedIcon;

@Getter private final MessageLog messageLog;
@Getter private LinedBoxPanel buttonsPanel;

private boolean registeredGlobalLog = false;

/**
 * Construct the frame.
 *
 * @param numLines number of lines to show at a time
 * @param colorEnabled true to enable a colored console
 */
public ConsoleFrame(int numLines, boolean colorEnabled) {
    this(SharedLocale.tr("console.title"), numLines, colorEnabled);
}

/**
 * Construct the frame.
 * 
 * @param title the title of the window
 * @param numLines number of lines to show at a time
 * @param colorEnabled true to enable a colored console
 */
public ConsoleFrame(@NonNull String title, int numLines, boolean colorEnabled) {
    messageLog = new MessageLog(numLines, colorEnabled);
    trayRunningIcon = SwingHelper.createImage(Launcher.class, "tray_ok.png");
    trayClosedIcon = SwingHelper.createImage(Launcher.class, "tray_closed.png");

    setTitle(title);
    setIconImage(trayRunningIcon);

    setSize(new Dimension(650, 400));
    setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED); //This is the new line of code added to minimize the window on load
    initComponents();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
            performClose();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Add components to the frame.
 */
private void initComponents() {
    JButton pastebinButton = new JButton(SharedLocale.tr("console.uploadLog"));
    JButton clearLogButton = new JButton(SharedLocale.tr("console.clearLog"));
    buttonsPanel = new LinedBoxPanel(true);

    buttonsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
    buttonsPanel.addElement(pastebinButton);
    buttonsPanel.addElement(clearLogButton);

    add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(messageLog, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    clearLogButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            messageLog.clear();
        }
    });

    pastebinButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pastebinLog();
        }
    });

    hideMessages();
}

/**
 * Register the global logger if it hasn't been registered.
 */
private void registerLoggerHandler() {
    if (!registeredGlobalLog) {
        getMessageLog().registerLoggerHandler();
        registeredGlobalLog = true;
    }
}

/**
 * Attempt to perform window close.
 */
protected void performClose() {
    messageLog.detachGlobalHandler();
    messageLog.clear();
    registeredGlobalLog = false;
    dispose();
}

/**
 * Send the contents of the message log to a pastebin.
 */
private void pastebinLog() {
    String text = messageLog.getPastableText();
    // Not really bytes!
    messageLog.log(tr("console.pasteUploading", text.length()), messageLog.asHighlighted());

    PastebinPoster.paste(text, new PastebinPoster.PasteCallback() {
        @Override
        public void handleSuccess(String url) {
            messageLog.log(tr("console.pasteUploaded", url), messageLog.asHighlighted());
            SwingHelper.openURL(url, messageLog);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleError(String err) {
            messageLog.log(tr("console.pasteFailed", err), messageLog.asError());
        }
    });
}

public static void showMessages() {
    ConsoleFrame frame = globalFrame;
    if (frame == null) {
        frame = new ConsoleFrame(10000, false);
        globalFrame = frame;
        frame.setTitle(SharedLocale.tr("console.launcherConsoleTitle"));
        frame.registerLoggerHandler();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.registerLoggerHandler();
        frame.requestFocus();
    }
}

public static void hideMessages() {
    ConsoleFrame frame = globalFrame;
    if (frame != null) {
        frame.setVisible(false);
    }
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your last question. If you want to use the System tray then you should be reading up on [How to Use the System Tray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html) for an example to get you started. I don't know that you can just minimize a JFrame to the System Tray.

Comment: Ok cool, will read up on that next. Thank you! So just to confirm, the suggestion you gave in the previous question dropped the window to the taskbar?

Comment: `dropped the window to the taskbar? ` yes, the taskbar, not the system tray.